# Manipulating tikzpicture and includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I am trying to draw a cauldron with 2 images going in for cooking!
I thought of using `tikz` to draw the cauldron and ti include the images by adding them as nodes in the `tikzpicture` environment. However I cannot succeed in placing the images exactly where and how I want.

My output is

[image]

MY desired output would be to have the images symmetrically going inside the cauldron and the licquid inside it embracing them.

My MWE is the following

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    cauldron filler/.style={draw=black, outer color=black, inner color=black!50, postaction={fill=black, fill opacity=.5}},
    legs/.style={draw=black, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25},
    cauldron glow/.style={circular glow={fill=#1}},
    rim filler/.style={inner color=black!50, outer color=black},
    liquid/.style={inner color=#1, outer color=#1!75!black},
    pics/cauldron/.style n args=3{
      code={
        \path (-130:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-130, legs] {};
        \path (-50:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-50, legs] {};
        \path [cauldron filler] (0,0) circle (1.25*#1 and .9*#1);
        \path [rim filler] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (.975*#1 and 0.255*#1);
        \path [cauldron glow=#2] (0,.75*#1) circle (.75*#1 and .18*#1);
        \path [liquid=#3] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (0.825*#1 and 0.1725*#1);
      }
    }
  }
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (2,0) pic {cauldron={0.3\columnwidth}{Silver}{Lime}} ++(0,0);
    \node[rotate=45] (image1) at (3,2.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{Mean_Pulse}};
    \node[rotate=-45] (image2) at (0,2.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{Stack_2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Please note that it is only courteous to provide a link and properly attribute code which you appropriate from others. In some cases (including this one, I believe) it is also a licence requirement i.e. your right to use the code requires it. However, courtesy is a stronger argument, in my opinion.

Comment: @cfr If "get rolled back" means to receive any feedback, the answer is no.

Comment: @Ignasi OK. Now I understand. I read 'update' as modifying the question rather than the answer :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `clip` can help. Also a `grid` can help to position `nodes`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    cauldron filler/.style={draw=black, outer color=black, inner color=black!50, postaction={fill=black, fill opacity=.5}},
    legs/.style={draw=black, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25},
    cauldron glow/.style={circular glow={fill=#1}},
    rim filler/.style={inner color=black!50, outer color=black},
    liquid/.style={inner color=#1, outer color=#1!75!black},
    pics/cauldron/.style n args=3{
      code={
        \path (-130:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-130, legs] {};
        \path (-50:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-50, legs] {};
        \path [cauldron filler] (0,0) circle (1.25*#1 and .9*#1);
        \path [rim filler] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (.975*#1 and 0.255*#1);
        \path [cauldron glow=#2] (0,.75*#1) circle (.75*#1 and .18*#1);
        \path [liquid=#3] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (0.825*#1 and 0.1725*#1);
      }
    }
  }
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (2,0) pic {cauldron={0.3\columnwidth}{Silver}{Lime}} ++(0,0);
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (-2,2.5) rectangle (5,5);
    \node[rotate=60] (image1) at (3.5,2.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node[rotate=-45] (image2) at (1,2.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{example-image-b}};
    \end{scope}
%   \draw[red, help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: Alenanno's `ragged border`

As Alenanno suggested, a `ragged border` can be added to clipping rectangle. It produces a `boiling` effect. `decorations.pathmorphing` library must be also loaded.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shadows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    cauldron filler/.style={draw=black, outer color=black, inner color=black!50, postaction={fill=black, fill opacity=.5}},
    legs/.style={draw=black, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25},
    cauldron glow/.style={circular glow={fill=#1}},
    rim filler/.style={inner color=black!50, outer color=black},
    liquid/.style={inner color=#1, outer color=#1!75!black},
    pics/cauldron/.style n args=3{
      code={
        \path (-130:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-130, legs] {};
        \path (-50:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-50, legs] {};
        \path [cauldron filler] (0,0) circle (1.25*#1 and .9*#1);
        \path [rim filler] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (.975*#1 and 0.255*#1);
        \path [cauldron glow=#2] (0,.75*#1) circle (.75*#1 and .18*#1);
        \path [liquid=#3] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (0.825*#1 and 0.1725*#1);
      }
    },
    ragged border/.style={ decoration={random steps, segment length=1mm, amplitude=0.5mm},decorate,}
  }
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (2,0) pic {cauldron={0.3\columnwidth}{Silver}{Lime}} ++(0,0);
    \begin{scope}
    \clip[ragged border] (-2,2.5) rectangle (5,5);
    \node[rotate=60] (image1) at (3.5,2.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node[rotate=-45] (image2) at (1,2.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{example-image-b}};
    \end{scope}
%   \draw[red, help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good one. I don't know why I didn't think of it. But I have a suggestion I was trying to implement myself: if you add `ragged border/.style={ decoration={random steps, segment length=1mm, amplitude=0.5mm},decorate,}` to `\tikzset` and then you write `\clip[ragged border] ...`, it will simulate the liquid better.

Comment: @Alenanno Nice suggestion. I've included it.

Comment: I think you need to comment under the question to notify him (I guess). :D

Comment: @Alenanno You're right. I always forget it.